# Do AngularJs support true oop?

Tags: angularjs, oop

I tried many ways to implement oop in angularjs, could not find right way to accomplish it. Proper encapsulation, scope and polymorphism as other popular languages.

Comment: angularjs is not a language, it is a framework built in javascript, and therefore has the same limitations as javascript has.

Comment: Perhaps you will find [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) useful.

Answer (score 0):

[TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) is a nifty language that compiles to human-readable JavaScript and allows a more familiar class syntax for .NET and ActionScript 3 programmers.  It's work a look.

[Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/) also has a book called [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) that describes methods for writing OO style code in JS.  It's similar to what TypeScript compiles into.